# How do I find values on a file that corresponds to another file and print everything in the latter one?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have the following kind of file (file_1):

```
4.96798703303702 "YPL223C"
3.5545141639441 "YPL281C"
4.50082973953956 "YML042W"
5.43613972089831 "YMR107W"
4.81971559885503 "YBR072W"
4.31478270112112 "YDL204W"
3.66402710414498 "YBR117C"
5.79159144125629 "YMR175W"
3.02190667031174 "YMR250W"
```

Which I want to find the correspondents on file_2:

```
YPL223C
YBR117C
YPL223C
YBR117C
YMR175W
YMR175W
```

Then, I would like to copy the value from the first column of file_1 to a newly created second column on file_2, looking like this:

```
4.96798703303702 "YPL223C"
3.66402710414498 "YBR117C"
4.96798703303702 "YPL223C"
3.66402710414498 "YBR117C"
5.79159144125629 "YMR175W"
5.79159144125629 "YMR175W"
```

I've tried using `grep -F -f file_2 file_1`, but this doesn't take into consideration the repetitions, only printing:

```
4.96798703303702 "YPL223C"
3.66402710414498 "YBR117C"
5.79159144125629 "YMR175W"
```

Is there a way to print with the repetitions?

Comment: Sorry, fixed with the correct output.

Comment: Yes, I would like that. I just put the final desired output and forgot to add the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

file1=./file_1
file2=./file_2

while read -r n; do
    v=$(awk -v n="$n" '$2 ~ n {print $1}' "$file1")
    printf '%s "%s"\n' "$v" "$n"
done <"$file2"
```

**note:** this will print all output to stdout.

This will read each line in `file_2` and set its value to `n`.  It will then read `file_1` and look for a line in which the value of `n` exists in column 2, and print column 1, setting it to the variable `v`.  It will then print `n` and `v` in the format you desire which can be redirected as you wish.

---

To create a file:

```
#!/bin/sh

file1=./file_1
file2=./file_2

while read -r n; do
    v=$(awk -v n="$n" '$2 ~ n {print $1}' "$file1")
    printf '%s "%s"\n' "$v" "$n"
done <"$file2" > file_3
```

---

However since you want to add these values to `file_2` you can then simply overwrite `file_2` with `file_3` however I recommend running the above before this to ensure it produces the correct results.  Also it wouldn't hurt to back up both `file_1` and `file_2` before making any changes.

```
#!/bin/sh

file1=./file_1
file2=./file_2

while read -r n; do
    v=$(awk -v n="$n" '$2 ~ n {print $1}' "$file1")
    printf '%s "%s"\n' "$v" "$n"
done <"$file2" > file_3

mv file_3 "$file2"
```

Comment: It worked out like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LucasFarinazzoMarques: Awesome, glad I could help.  Note I have updated the answer to output in your desired format.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[substr($2,2,length($2)-2)] = $0; next} 
  {print a[$1]}
' file_1 file_2
4.96798703303702 "YPL223C"
3.66402710414498 "YBR117C"
4.96798703303702 "YPL223C"
3.66402710414498 "YBR117C"
5.79159144125629 "YMR175W"
5.79159144125629 "YMR175W"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below script and worked very much fine

```
for i in `cat file2`; do j=`sed -n '/'$i'/p' file1|awk '{print $1}'`; k=`awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i {print $0}' file2|sort | uniq| awk '{print NF}'`; if [[ $k == 1 ]]; then sed -i "/$i/s/.*/& $j/g" file2; fi; done
```

output

```
YPL223C 4.96798703303702
YBR117C 3.66402710414498
YPL223C 4.96798703303702
YBR117C 3.66402710414498
YMR175W 5.79159144125629
YMR175W 5.79159144125629
```